# How do I turn this image to a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

This is the image:

```
<%= image_tag comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny) %>
```

and here is the link path:

```
comment.user.profile
```

Now how do I combine these two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<%= link_to image_tag(comment.user.profile.photo.url(:tiny)), comment.user.profile %>
```